# Newbie question for Flex Remoting with WebOrb

Tags: apache-flex, iis, weborb, remoteobject

Since Flashbuilder does not support WCF over https, i am considering to use weborb remoting as alternative, but not really sure how flash is going to know weborb location, if they are sitting on different servers. Looked at destination, source fields, but not really find a field called url in remoteObject in Flex. Has anyone done similar things?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but thought I'd answer it anyway. You can expose your WCF services to remoting clients (Flash, Flex) via WebORB. WebORB supports both self-host and IIS-hosted WCF services. Here are links to instructions for both models.

**Self-hosted:** http://www.themidnightcoders.com/fileadmin/docs/dotnet/v4/guide/index.html?standalone_wcf_services.htm

**IIS-hosted:** http://www.themidnightcoders.com/fileadmin/docs/dotnet/v4/guide/index.html?iis_hosted_wcf_services.htm

Both documents address your questions. Here is an example of one approach:

Invoking Self-Hosted Service From Flex/AIR
Flex and AIR clients can use the RemoteObject API to invoke methods on self-hosted WCF services which use the AMF endpoint. There are two approaches for invoking self-hosted WCF service. The first approach requires less code, but creates a dependency on configuration files declaring destinations and channels (the files located in WEB-INF/flex). The second approach does not have any dependencies on the configuration files, but results in a few additional lines of code.Consider the examples of the API below:

Approach 1 (with dependency on configuration files):

var remoteObject:RemoteObject = new RemoteObject("GenericDestination");
remoteObject.endpoint = "http://localhost:8000/WCFAMFExample/amf"
remoteObject.GetQuote.addEventListener( ResultEvent.RESULT, gotResult );
remoteObject.GetQuote.addEventListener( FaultEvent.FAULT, gotError );
remoteObject.GetQuote( "name" );

The endpoint URL uniquely identifies the WCF service. Notice the /amf at the end of the URL, it is required for the AMF endpoint. With the approach demonstrated above, the destination name in the RemoteObject constructor is required however it is not used. As a result, for the code to work, the Flex/AIR application must be compiled with additional compile argument:

-services "C:\Program Files\WebORB for .NET\4.0\web-inf\flex\services-config.xml"

I hope this helps.

K